# Можно ли сделать другом класса функцию другого класса?

Tags: c++, ооп, классы

Имеется два класса Koords и Comlexity. В класс Complexity входит один объект класса Koords, при этом в классе Complexity есть функция, котороя оперирует значениями объекта Koords. Для удобства хочется, чтобы эта функция могла обращаться непосредственно к членам класса Koords - для этого я сделал Complexity другом Koords. Но вот мне интересно, а можно ли сделать другом только необходимую функцию, а не весь класс?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пуркуа бы и не па?

```
class B;

class A
{
public:
    void Friend(B&);
    void Enemy(B&);
};

class B
{
public:
    B(int x):x(x){}
private:
    int x;

    friend void A::Friend(B&);
};

void A::Friend(B&b) { cout << b.x << endl; }
void A::Enemy(B&b) { cout << b.x << endl; }

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    B b(5);
    A a;
    a.Friend(b);
    a.Enemy(b);
}
```

Попробуйте скомпилировать - проблемы будут только в `Enemy`...